# Why does AllowBlobPublicAccess of Get-AzStorageAccount cmdlet return NULL when it is clear that public access is enabled?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cli

I was running the cmdlet `Get-AzStorageAccount` on a storage account to test whether public access is enabled.

### Azure portal

[image]

### Azure PowerShell

[image]

### Similar results via CLI

```
az storage account show -g MyResourceGroup -n MyStorageAccount
```

[image]

### Question

For a while I was under the impression that the cmdlet works only on `StorageV2` accounts. But, I can confirm that this is not the case. The cmdlet is inconsistent with both `StorageV2` and `General purpose V1` accounts.

I am unable to understand the reason for the inconsistent behaviour of the cmdlet `Get-AzStorageAccount` w.r.t property `AllowPublicBlobAccess` ?

thank you,

Sau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#allow-or-disallow-public-read-access-for-a-storage-account) shows in the `Note`:

> The AllowBlobPublicAccess property is not set by default and does not
> return a value until you explicitly set it. The storage account
> permits public access when the property value is null or when it is
> true.

You need to disable it and save, then enable it. The property will be `true` that you want.

[image]

Comment: Agree. After reading the documentation, the behaviour make more sense now.

Comment: What's the Powershell command equivalent to that above Azure CLI?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=powershell#allow-or-disallow-public-read-access-for-a-storage-account) also contain the powershell commands.